# Call function after [self back]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I need pass from one ViewController to second just calling [self back] and open the alertView after back function. Is it possible ?

EDIT:

in FirstViewController:

```
- (void)didPressBuyPackageButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title "
                                                        message:@"Message "
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Koupit",@"Obnovit koupu", nil];

    switch (button.tag) {
        case 1: // Texty pre balicek c. 1 (Rocnik 2 - Balicek 1)
            alertView.title = @"Ročník 2";
            alertView.message = @"Tu bude popis čo balíček obsahuje.";
            alertView.tag = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            alertView.title = @"Ročník 2 - Balíček 2";
            alertView.message = @"Tu bude popis čo balíček obsahuje.";
            alertView.tag = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            alertView.title = @"Ročník 3 - Balíček 1";
            alertView.message = @"Tu bude popis čo balíček obsahuje.";
            alertView.tag = 3;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    [alertView show];    
}
```

And What I need is call function back from SECOND_ViewController which display FirstViewController and call Function "didPressBuyPackageButton" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in the context of the second view controller, the you can call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` from it to transition back to the first view controller. It provides you a completion callback that you can use to show the `UIAlertView`.

**edit:**

```
- (void)back {
    // get a reference to presentingViewController
    FirstViewController *presentingViewController = (FirstViewController *)self.presentingViewController;

    // dismiss the second view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{
        // show the alert
        [presentingViewController showAlert];
    }];
}
```

You need to call `back` from the second view controller.

On other way to do it is to use delegation: The first view controller instantiates the second view controller and set itself as the second view controller's delegate. In `back` (second view controller), just notify your delegate (first view controller) that it (second view controller) has completed and dismiss it. Use completion block to handle the end of the animation. Same trick.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to open alertView from FirstViewController after calling back ....

Comment: Just grab a reference to the `presentingViewController` then. Made an edit.

Comment: I added a code sample what I need :) hope that helps for you... Thank you !

Comment: Many thanks, I forgot to declare selector in .h file and your code worked ! :)